# How to specify multiple roles to authenticate the JNDIRealm in Tomcat 9

Tags: authentication, tomcat, ldap, authorization, tomcat9

In a Tomcat 9 I have a LDAP authentication running via the JNDIRealm. So my `server.xml` contains:

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
                connectionURL="ldap://mysub.mydomain.com:1234"
                userSubtree="true"
                userBase="OU=Name A,OU=Name B,DC=doma,DC=domb,DC=com"
                userSearch="(xyzAccountName={0})"
                userRoleName="memberof"
                roleBase="OU=Groups,DC=doma,DC=domb,DC=com"
                roleName="CN"
                roleSearch="(memberOf={0})"
                roleSubtree="true"
        roleNested="true"/>
```

When I use this in a JSP page displaying `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()` I see:

> GenericPrincipal[USERNAME(CN=Special Users,OU=Name C,OU=Groups,DC=doma,DC=domb,DC=com,CN=Other Users,OU=Name D,DC=doma,DC=domb,DC=com,CN=All Users,OU=Name D,DC=doma,DC=domb,DC=com,)]

So the user `USERNAME` is authenticated  via the roles `Special Users`, `Other Users` and  `All Users`.

I now want that only users with the roles `Special Users` and `Other Users` are allowed to see this JSP page. Users who have *only* `the All Users` role should be rejected (getting a 401 or 403 error) from Tomcat.

How do I do this? I tried setting

```
userRoleName="Special Users,Other Users"
```

in the JNDIRealm, but that doesn't work at all.

Comment: Note the current config attempts to assign roles read from the user entry (via userRoleName) and (in addition) those matching the role search (via roleName/roleSearch). Now these 3 roles you got for that user are retrieved from the `memberOf` attribute of the user entry, not from the role search (because the filter is wrong), and the problem is that you can only filter roles via the search filter. In other words you would need to _not_ use userRoleName, and make the role search work, so that you can then add to it a second filter for the mandatory roles. Can you add user/role entry sample ?

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks a lot for chiming in! You say _mot_ to use `userRoleName`, right? So I just leave it out, ok. But _where_ then do I specify the two security groups (`Special Users` and `Other Users`) which should be allowed? Also, what do you mean by "user/role entry sample"?

Comment: For the _where_, you specify it via `roleSearch`. 1. "make the role search work", as `{0}` refers to the user's dn, the filter should apply to role groups having that user as a _member_ : `roleSearch="(member={0})"` 2. "so that you can then add to it a second filter for the mandatory roles" : `roleSearch="(&(member={0})(|(cn=Special Users)(cn=Other Users))"`. For the user/role entry samples I was referring to LDIF entry records, it might be simpler to get to a solution knowing what they look like.

Comment: For example, you might need to use `uniqueMember` instead of `member`, if your groups  are defined as groupOfUniqueNames (objectClass), the information is in any (role) group entry.

Comment: @EricLavault Super interesting! Thanks. I have tried your suggestion for `roleSearch`, but then none can access the site. So I guess I need to find out the LDIF entries for different people.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed the filter is missing a closing parenthesis.. it could be because of that. You can use [ldapsearch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) or equivalent to see what an ldap entry looks like.